# Why does the output file come up empty

Tags: c++, asynchronous, future

I'm working on a program that is supposed to make use of async and futures but i have come across a problem. When an output file is created nothing is in the file. It is just a blank file. I'm not sure if the issue s with reading the original file or write onto a new one I'm also usure if I have properly utilized async so any corrections would be a appreciated.

```
   #include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
int prnumber;
static bool bCheckFinished = false;

string guess;

bool process(std::string sFileIn, std::string sFileOut) {
    ifstream in(sFileIn);
    vector<vector<string>> vsFields;

    ofstream outPutFile;
    outPutFile.open(sFileOut, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);

    if (in) {
        string sLine;

        while (getline(in, sLine)) {
            stringstream sep(sLine);
            string sField;

            vsFields.push_back(vector<string>());

            while (getline(sep, sField, ',')) {
                vsFields.front().push_back(sField);
            }
        }
    }


    if (outPutFile.is_open()) {
        for (auto row : vsFields) {
            for (auto field : row) {
                outPutFile << field << "," << std::endl;
            }
        }

    }
    std::cout << "\n File Successfully Read!" << std::endl;
    return true;

}
bool prime(int prnumber) {

    std::cout << "Please enter a number" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> prnumber;
    std::cout << "Processing" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 2; i < prnumber; ++i) if (prnumber%i == 0) return false;
    return true;

}

int main() {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();


    std::future<bool> fileProcA = std::async(process, "unigram_freq.cvs", "Word_list.txt");
    std::future<bool> fut = std::async(prime, prnumber);

    
    bool pr = fut.get();

    bool fileProc = false;

    while (!fileProc) {
        fileProc = fileProcA.get();
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();


    if (pr) std::cout << "The number is prime!" << endl;
    else std::cout << "It is not prime";

    double elapsed = (std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(end - start).count());
    std::cout << "The time elapsed is " << elapsed << "ms" << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through this code with your debugger to verify that the input and output files open successfully, that `vsFields` is populated with values, etc.?

Comment: No, How would i do that?

Comment: It's going to depend on your development environment (operating system, choice of editor, etc.).  For example, [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-tutorial-debugging-overview/) is a tutorial for Visual Studio, and [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/index.htm)'s a tutorial for the Linux command line tool `gdb`.

Comment: Another common option for smaller projects is to simply add extra `cout`s around places where you think the bug might live to inspect the values that way.  Fine for simple bugs, but doesn't scale that well, which is why I recommend you learn to use a debugger.  Also, [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog post gets posted around here a lot - it contains some other tips for how to approach solving this kind of problem.